# How to foreach loop in table 3 column using php

Tags: php, html, loops

I have code like this

```
<table>
<tr>
   <th>No</th>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>Name</th>
</tr>    
foreach($value as $item){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$item['no']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item['title]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item['data']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
</table>
```

For example I have 5 items in my loop. My loop output now something like this:

```
| No |   Title  |  Name |
|----|----------|-------|
| 1  |    Book  | Susan |
| 2  |   Comic  |  Budi |
| 3  |   Recipe | Anwar |
| 4  |  Magazine|  Leo  |
| 5  |   Novel  | Clara |
```

But I want output like this with the looping header also
[image]

Comment: Why would you want it this way? How is this more useful to the reader than row by row?

Answer (score 1):

You may try `array_chunk` to split array as 3 items in each row first.

```
$value = [
    ['no' => '1', 'title' => 'Book', 'data' => 'Susan'],
    ['no' => '2', 'title' => 'Comic', 'data' => 'Budi'],
    ['no' => '3', 'title' => 'Recipe', 'data' => 'Anwar'],
    ['no' => '4', 'title' => 'Magazine', 'data' => 'Leo'],
    ['no' => '5', 'title' => 'Novel', 'data' => 'Clara']
];

$value = array_chunk($value, 3);

echo '<table>';
foreach ($value as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo '<td>'.$item['no'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$item['title'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$item['data'].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify and use modulus operator to close raw and open raw.

replace your loop data and test it.

```
$i = 1;
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($row as $item) {
    echo '<td>'.$item['no'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$item['title'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$item['data'].'</td>';
    if($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
}
```